# Error when formatting JSON string

Tags: c#, windows

JSON data is

```
"participant": {"id": "1"},
```

I tried the following code.But I got a exception

```
String.Format(("\n\"{0}\":{\"{1}\":\"{2}\"}","participant","id","1"));
```

Exception is

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: Escape your curly braces

Comment: You should include the exception within your question.

Comment: @ Jason Goemaat Can u please write your correction please.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Calling `string.Format` with no placeholders is pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have curly braces in a string.Format call, you need to escape them using double curly braces.

For example:

```
var str = string.Format("\"{0}\": {{ \"id\": \"{1}\" }}", "participant", 5);
```

In string.Format, you use placeholders which are numerically ordered from 0 (zero) to whatever you need. These are placed in single curly braces, hence the need to escape your json curly braces.

Another option would be to use one of the many Json libraries to do the serialization for you, for example Json.NET (http://james.newtonking.com/json)

eg.

```
var anon = new { participant = "bob", id = 5 };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anon);
```